# Learning Python the Hard Way: Exercise 38 (How functions work in Python)

Tags: python

I am reading Zed Shaw's 'Learning Python the Hard Way'and am working on Exercise 38. I have come across his section on how functions work in Python and am stuck on his example as shown below:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41)
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits", or "license" for more information.
>>> class Thing(object):
...    def test(hi):
...            print "hi"
...
>>> a = Thing()
>>> a.test("hello")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: test() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
>>>
```

After reading the explanation at the end, the Zed explains that Python changed a.test("hello") to test(a, "hello") and that somewhere someone messed up and didn't add an argument for a.

Would someone kindly explain this concept further to me? I don't quite understand what is meant by needing to "add an argument for a." If someone explain this error to me that would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints. The thing you're missing in your posted code is the `self` argument for the current instance (which the method doesn't need, suggesting it shouldn't actually *be* an instance method).

Comment: Just the fact that you've got to chapter 38 and are only now learning about functions - one of the fundamental building blocks of programming - should give you some idea of why that tutorial is not recommended.

Answer (score 3):

The example should've been:

```
>>> class Thing(object):
...     def test(self, hi):
...             print hi
...
>>> a = Thing()
>>> a.test("Hello")
Hello
```

Which works as expected.

All functions[1] in classes need to take an additional argument, usually called `self`. It's used to refer to the object of the class the function is being called from.

Also, `"hi"`, should've been just `hi`, minus the quotes, quotes make it a string literal instead of a variable.

[1] Except a special class of functions called [static functions/methods](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod).

Answer (score 1):

The example was given to help understand the internal processes when Python encounters something like `mystuff.append('hello')` and breaks it down, and compares to a very similar statement `a.test("hello")` and that knowing this internal process can be handy to interpret errors such as the one given.

He wants you to start thinking of a list (or a variable that represents a list) as an *object*. And *list objects* have their own built-in functions (such as *append*) which are unique to lists. Internally python sends the list itself to the append function automatically when called, as explained in the 5 points about what's going on when Python processes `mystuff.append('hello')`

He then briefly introduces something completely new - a class. We haven't encountered classes at this point in the book yet, this is just to plant a seed in your head for upcoming chapters. A class is a self-defined type of object, and just like the list object, it can have its own functions.

The Thing class contains a `test(message)` function, just like Python's built-in list object. But read items 4 and 5 when he discusses what's going on with Python's internal processes on `mystuff.append('hello')`

> 4. Next Python sees the ( (open parenthesis) and realizes, "Oh hey, this should be a function." At this point it calls the function just like normal, but it calls the function with an *extra* argument.
> 5. That *extra* argument is **mystuff**! I know, weird, right? But that's how Python works, so it's best to remember it and assume that's the result. **What happens at the end of all this is, a function that looks like append(mystuff, 'hello')**

So the built-in *append* function (which is a part of all list types of objects), automatically sends the list object itself as the first argument.  Likewise, when if you make your own objects, like **Thing** object, any functions within also have to accept `self` as the first argument.

He demonstrates this by calling `a.test("hello")` using the correct syntax (exact same as `mystuff.append('hello')` ) but we get this error!  The syntax is valid, but the error gives us clues about what's going on *under the hood*... and in this case, the problem is a function in our **Thing** class which is missing an argument, being self.

> somewhere someone messed up and didn't add the argument for a.

i.e.

`mystuff.append('hello')` is to  `append(mystuff, 'hello')`

and therefore,

`a.test("hello")` is to  `test(a, "hello")`

Once we include that first argument (self), this will resolve the error
`def test(self, message)`   It's just a demonstration about error reporting, don't get too hung up on this one, but it gets you thinking about the concept of an object needing to send itself (self) as an argument to a built-in function within the object.